# Portable Haskell code

Tags: haskell, portability

Is it possible to verify that given `.hs` source is portable to any architecture assuming there is Haskell compiler available for it? How to verify that imported modules are also portable?

Comment: No, it's not possible in general.  A library can be Haskell 98 or Haskell 2010 and still import modules that aren't.  And even modules that are Haskell98 can make platform dependent assumptions.

Comment: As a simple example, imagine you have a Haskell program that reads the file `c:\dos\attr`.  Rather few platforms include such a file by default.

Comment: While those are valid comments, I do think it should be possible to verify this for a large class of programs (e.g. which only do IO on the standard streams and use no FFI / unsafe functions).

Comment: @leftaroundabout, yes especially if the majority of the codebase is pure and not involving the IO type and using as few extensions as possible. Then the impure part, which may be a file or two can be manually verified for which platforms it supports.